# Vector form for the tangent line of a graph at a particular point

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

The question that I am trying to solve is as follows:

Determine the vector form for the tangent line to the graph of $y=2x^2-2x$ at $x=3$.

In order to solve this problem, I first calculated the tangent line at $x=3$, which I found to be $y=10x-18$. However, I am not sure how to transform this equation into 'vector form'.

My textbook defines the 'vector equation/form' of a line to be $\vec{r}=\vec{r}_0+t\vec{v}$, where $\vec{v}$ is a vector parallel to the line, and $\vec{r}_0$ and $\vec{r}$ are the position vectors of $\vec{P}_0$ and $\vec{P}$, respectively.

I attempted to convert this equation to vector form by taking two points on the line and calculating the vector between them, which is parallel to the tangent line. For my work, I chose $(2,2)$ and $(3,12),$ giving a vector of $\langle1,10\rangle$. I then picked an arbitrary point for $\vec{r}_0$, namely, $(2,2).$

Thus, my final answer was $(2i+2j)+t(i+10j)$, where $i$ and $j$ are standard basis vectors with length 1. However, according to my teacher, this is not the correct answer. Where exactly am I going wrong? 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I do not see anything wrong with your solution. Maybe I would just write the final answer like this: $x(t) = 2+t, y(t)= 2+10t, t \in \mathbb{R}$, but in principle there is nothing wrong with your way of writing it. Working on the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ you do not have the unit vector $k$.

Comment: I'd ask your professor to see what the problem is. Your answer is perfectly correct.

Comment: Looks right to me. Maybe try writing it as $(2+t)\mathbf{i} + (2+10t)\mathbf{j}$

Comment: Thank you all for your help! @DavidReed I thought about this format, and then on a whim tried $\langle2+t, 2+10t\rangle$, which was the correct answer. It turns out that he wanted to emphasize the difference between the 'vector equation' of a line (which was what I originally got for my answer) and the 'vector form' of a line.